Slew drive 12 volt motor with 7 wires
I have just acquired a slew drive for my solar tracker but it has 7 wires…
3 thick and 4 thin. The thick are positive negative and earth and the other 4 thin wires are for a controller. I don’t know where the 4 thin wires should be connected to , what is hall a and b and what is hall gnd and + 5..what do these mean..does anyone know…can you explain…I’ve tried asking the manufacturer but I think they assume their drives are sold only to electrical engineers…I hope you can help..thank you..Mike

Welcome! "assume their drives are sold only to electrical engineers" They aren't wrong. This motor would be integrated into a product by a manufacturer by engineers. Have you searched on how Hall effect sensors are used in a motor? What did you find out? If you don't need Hall sensors, just ignore them and use motor+ and motor-?

You have a DC motor (thick red and black wires). When you apply the appropriate voltage (24V?) the motor will run in one direction. Reverse the polarity and it will run in the other direction. There is also a thick green wire that is intended to be connected to earth.
Perhaps there are clutches or limit switches at the end of travel, or not, I don't know what you've got.
The other wires are for a an (incremental) encoder that picks up quadrature signals from the rotation of the motor so that the motor can be controlled to move a (relatively) precise amount. Grey and brown are circuit ground and + supply respectively. The other two wires are Hall sensor outputs that will pulse as the motor runs. They may or may not require a pullup resistor to the supply (a bit of the page you've shown seems to suggest a particular value).

The Wikipedia image above makes some assumption of A and B but there is no standard, it could be inverted or there may not be clean separation for some of the edges (but there will be for at least two in order for it to work properly).
From the pulses you can read both the amount of motion and the direction, however since this is an incremental encoder the starting position will be unknown to the encoder.

Thank you so much…yes I did google Hall effect sensors and yes most of it went over my head…as did much of Spehro's….but it has become a little clearer…all I need to do is to turn the motor both ways, as in changing the polarity.  The slew drive will rotate the solar panels from east to west…as the sun moves, the tracker controller tells the slew drive which way to turn, as soon as it is facing the sun, it turns off…so I don’t need and clutches or limit switches.

It’s a very simple set up. To move the panels north south, I have a 12 volt linear actuator with the same principle of switching polarity.  So if I simply connect the + and - red and black wires to the controller, I can disregard the others, I’m not doing the motor any harm…can I test it by simply connecting a 12 volt battery and switching the polarity? I knew I was up against electrical geniuses finding this site so please excuse my ignorance and thank you for the kind support….Mike
